# SQL , SQL QUERIES

Tags: sql

I have the following condition:

if column is NULL, or have value like `Unassessed` or `ABC` then the result should be `I`.

I need help how to put three in one condition like below. Just confused with NULL value. And it is string in column.

```
JobAssessStage  ='Unassessed','','ABC'

JobAssessStage in ('Unassessed','','ABC')
```

Comment: share sample data and output

Answer (score 1):

Use below condition with is null

```
JobAssessStage in ('Unassessed','ABC') or JobAssessStage is null
```

Answer (score 1):

use `case when` for multiple condition

```
select case when JobAssessStage in ('Unassessed','ABC') or    
JobAssessStage is null then 'I' else 'You' End
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you can use also use COALESCE function (it returns the first non-null expression in a list) on JobAssessStage field:

```
COALESCE(JobAssessStage, 'X') in ('Unassessed','ABC','X')
```

If JobAssessStage is NULL with COALESCE the value you're testing becomes X.

I told you "in some cases" because you have to be sure that the value you have chosen (X) is not a value that your field can take.

Answer (score 0):

You can formulate your like below:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND (JobAssessStage IN ('Unassessed', 'ABC') 
       OR JobAssessStage IS NULL);
```